# Call contract function from truffle console

Tags: solidity, truffle

I want to call a fucntion of deployed contract not deployed by me (I have a contract address and ABI), is it possible to do from truffle console? There are a lot of examples how to do it using js, but not using truffle. If it's possible, could you please provide me few examples?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have the source of the contract? It should be possible in any case, but it is easier with the source code.

Comment: @Ismael yes, I have a solidity sourcecode

Comment: The idea is to create a dummy project and add the source code to the contracts/ directory and configure to connect to the correct network. Once compiled you can launch console and run `instance = await CompiledContract.at("0x123413241234....")`, then you can call contracts with `instance.sayHello("params")`.

Comment: @Ismael, thanks for the answer. Do I have to migrate(deploy) this dummy project? Or just a compile will be enough?  Also, as I know, at() function is depricated in truffle.

Comment: It is not necessary to deploy, compiling is enough. I didn't know about at being deprecated, it works in truffle 5.1.17.  I'd assume there is some kind of replacement.